# Can't mount NFS shares on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount a NFS share on two Raspberry Pi, both running raspbian buster, but I can't. The same commands and steps issued on several VMs that I have running Debian buster minimal, work as expected, and shares do mount.

On the server, Ubuntu Focal:

```
~# cat /etc/exports
/export 192.168.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0) 192.168.50.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0) 192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
/export/media 192.168.50.202/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1020,anongid=1020,fsid=1)
/export/backup 192.168.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,nohide) 192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,nohide) 192.168.50.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,nohide)

~# cat /etc/fstab
...
/media/media          /export/media         none    bind  0  0
/mnt/disk4/backup /export/backup none    bind  0  0

~# showmount -e
Export list for nas:
/export/backup      192.168.50.0/24,192.168.0.0/24,192.168.10.0/24
/export/media       192.168.50.202/24
/export             192.168.0.0/24,192.168.50.0/24,192.168.10.0/24

~# cat /etc/hosts.allow
ALL:ALL
```

On the client:

```
~# ll /mnt
total 20K
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4,0K may 14 17:06 backup/

~# showmount -e 192.168.10.200
# It delays a bit, but finally shows:

Export list for 192.168.10.200:
/export/backup      192.168.50.0/24,192.168.0.0/24,192.168.10.0/24
/export/media       192.168.50.202/24
/export             192.168.0.0/24,192.168.50.0/24,192.168.10.0/24

~# mount -vvv -t nfs 192.168.10.200:/backup /mnt/backup
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu May 14 20:18:34 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.10.200,clientaddr=192.168.10.66'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=192.168.10.200,clientaddr=192.168.10.66'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out

~# rpcinfo -p 192.168.10.200
192.168.10.200: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
```

On one of those rPi-like VMs:

```
~# rpcinfo -p 192.168.10.200
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  44923  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  59269  mountd
    100005    2   udp  56604  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  56815  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  41383  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  41383  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  41383  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  39469  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  39469  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  39469  nlockmgr
```

I've tried anything I can imagine. I've disabled FW on both server and Pis. I've temporarily disabled the router FW. I've moved one Rpi to the same physical network of the nas...
Nothing strange is shown in dmesg. I'll thank some help.

Edit: Still can't mount a nfs share on any ARM platform. Adding more info:
I received a new OPIZero, that I flashed with ARMbian. Leaving it plain Jane only installing nfs-common I get the same results. I've tried:

- Configuring NFS server ports fixed as per
  https://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS instructions.
- Creating rules in both server(s) and client fw, though I disabled them before
- Putting client in the same network interface as the server
- Completely disabling Esxi fw, were NFS server is hosted
- Inspect interfaces MTU config for mismatches
- Completely disabling the network firewall. It showed no NFS traffic during queries.
- Doing a tcpdump trace at the server. It shows no queries from client other than ARP and NTP.
- Setting up my personal machine (Ubuntu 20.04) as NFS server (at the same VLAN/Interface), sharing a dummy folder.

Iptables on client:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports sunrpc,nfs,32764:32769
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports sunrpc,nfs,32764:32769

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports sunrpc,nfs,32764:32769
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports sunrpc,nfs,32764:32769
```

Setting up a fresh NFS server out of the Hypervisor and in the same interface didn't do.
It seems to me that any Debian Buster ARM distro is failing at doing rpc queries. There's no traffic coming out of the rPi (nfs traffic, other do work) I can only see 111 port queries output. When it has to establish udp it fails.
What lasts for me is flashing Ubuntu arm to see if it shows the same problem.

I'm running out of ideas here and I need a backup connection.

NOTE: All other AMD64 machines, inside and outside the Esxi server, at the same or different VLAN can and mount NFS shares. Only Raspbian/Armbian don't do.

Comment: Do you have the NTFS-3g package installed on your system?

Comment: Since showmount seems to take a while, this makes me wonder about your network configuration. You seem to have 3 different subnets (192.168.50.x, 192.168.10.x, and 192.168.0.x). What are the IP addresses of the Ubuntu and Pi? If they are in different subnets, how are they all connected together?

Comment: @bls I have a opnsense instance that routes between vlans. The nas is at x.x.10.200 and the PIs are one at x.x.50.203 and the other at x.x.0.20. That is not a problem and the other appliances are so alike. Also, I bypassed the firewall and unified the vlans without making a difference.

Comment: @Sergio, I'd start with making sure that UDP works across your vlans correctly. iperf3 might be a good tool for that.

Comment: Are you mixing nfs3 on the server and nfs4 on the client?

Comment: AFAIK the server is able to serve nfs4 and 3. I activated the nfsd debug and what I can see is that the server receives and autorizes at port 2049, but when client switches to high/upd ports to continue the mount, nothing arrives to server and times out.